# Write a program using conditional compilation directives to round off the number 56 to nearest fifties

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Write a program using conditional compilation directives to round off the number 56 to nearest fifties.

Expected Output: 50

Where is the mistake?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define R 50
int main()
{
       int Div;
       Div = R % 50;
       cout<<"Div:: "<<Div;
       printf("\n");

#if(Div<=24)
{
       int Q;
       printf("Rounding down\n");
       Q =(int(R /50))*50;
       printf("%d",Q);
}
#else
{
       int Q;
       printf("Rounding UP\n");
       Q =(int(R/50)+1)*50;
       printf("%d",Q);
}
#endif
}
```

Comment: *where is mistake?* What behaivior did you see that prompted you to conclude that the program is not working as expected?

Comment: Maybe I'm confused but shouldn't your mod test tell you whether you need to round up or down because the % operator returns the remainder of the division, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only sense-making way of interpreting the homework task is to consider 56 as an example and to require a compile-time constant result for any given integer number. The only sense-making way of *using conditional compilation directives* is taking also negative numbers into account.

```
#ifndef NUMBER
#define NUMBER  56
#endif
#if NUMBER < 0
#define ROUNDED (NUMBER-25)/50*50
#else
#define ROUNDED (NUMBER+25)/50*50
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

`Div` is a variable and so cannot be evaluated in a preprocessing directive because preprocessing happens before your source code is compiled.

Since the preprocessor does not understand variables it gives the *token* `Div` an arbitrary value of `0` when using it in an arithmetic expression. This means your program appears to work. However if you changed the value of `R` to say 99, you would see in that case the code does not work.

This version without `Div` works in all cases.

```
#define R 50

#if R % 50 <= 24
   int Q;
   printf("Rounding down\n");
   Q =(int(R /50))*50;
   printf("%d",Q);
#else
   int Q;
   printf("Rounding UP\n");
   Q =(int(R/50)+1)*50;
   printf("%d",Q);
#endif
```

It's a really, really pointless task that you have been set. I feel embarassed even attempting an answer.